# Передача сущности бота в соседний скрипт

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Появилась загвоздка при формировании некой архитектуры бота.
Есть два файла:

- app.js - стартовый файл с инициализацией основных компонентов
- commands.js - файл с ответами на запросы пользователя

**app.js**

```js
const TelegramAPI = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
...
const bot = new TelegramAPI(token, {polling: true});
...
console.log(bot);
...
module.exports = {
    bot
}
```

**commands.js**

```js
const { bot } = require("./app.js")

function answer()
{
    console.log(bot);

    return bot.sendMessage(...);
}
```

Проблема как раз в передаче сущности бота во второй скрипт. В первом случае лог показывает всю информацию о боте и все работает как надо. Во втором же файле, при попытке вывести информацию о боте, выбивает `undefined`. При попытке отправить сообщение `error: [polling_error] {}`.
Вопрос в том, как можно (возможно ли) передать сущность `bot` в другой файл и использовать ее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуй вот такой вариант...

```
const TelegramAPI = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
...
const bot = new TelegramAPI(token, {polling: true});
...
console.log(bot);
...
const getBot = _ => bot
...
module.exports = {
    getBot
}
```

Ну и

```
const { getBot } = require("./app.js")

function answer()
{
    const bot = getBot()
    console.log(bot);

    return bot.sendMessage(...);
}
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, и мой, и твой варианты рабочие. Я только потом заметил, что у меня создалась цепочка из нескольких файлов и зависимостей. И в commands.js эта цепочка замкнулась, из-за чего `bot` и не передавался. Как оказывается, так делать нельзя. Но спасибо за предложение.